# How to save/load Google-Cloud-Vision OCR protobuf response to disk?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to save responses from Google-Cloud-Vision OCR to disk and found gzipping and storing the actual protobuf is the most space efficient option for later processing. That part was easy! Now how do I retrieve and parse that back from disk into its original format?

My question is: Where/how do I rebuild the message_pb2 file to parse the file back into protobuf

Following [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial) Here's my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding: utf-8

from google.cloud import vision
import gzip, os, io


def ocr_document(path):
    """
    Detects document features in an image.
    Returns response protobuf from API.
    """
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = vision.types.Image(content=content)

    response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)

    return(response)

response = ocr_document('handwritten-scan.jpg')
serialized = response.SerializeToString()


with gzip.open('response.pb.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(serialized)
print(os.path.getsize('response.pb.gz'), 'bytes') # Output: 11032 bytes

# Figure this part out!

with gzip.open('response.pb.gz', 'rb') as f:
    serialized=f.read()
    ### parsed = message_pb2.Message()  # < - Protobuf message I'm missing
    parsed.ParseFromString(serialized)
    print(parsed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the code, here's the answer:

```
from google.cloud.vision_v1.proto import image_annotator_pb2
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict

with gzip.open('response.pb.gz', 'rb') as lf:
    Loaded=lf.read()
    parsed = image_annotator_pb2.AnnotateImageResponse()
    parsed.ParseFromString(Loaded)

print(MessageToDict(parsed))
```